# PC can not receive an IP address while my router can

Tags: windows, networking, ip

**Situation**

Recently I changed my local network architecture a bit, because of which I now connect directly to my modem with a UTP cable to my pc instead of over wi-fi via a separate router.

For some reason though, my PC can't obtain an IP address (it says it's connected to an "unidentified network"). If I switch the ports on the modem for my router and my PC I have the same problem, my router keeps working in both situations.

Does anyone know what could be the problem here? I'm at a loss.

**Specs**

- Windows 8
- Realtek network card
- feel free to ask more stuff :)

EDIT: Some extra info, when I type `ipconfig /renew` in my command prompt I get the following error: `An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.`

Comment: Obviously you're doing something wrong. What was your IP when you were connecting via Wi-Fi? Was it something from RFC 1918 addresses (192.168.x.x, 172.x.x.x, 10.x.x.x)? I think your router was your DHCP server and on one of his interfaces it just gets a public IP address from your provider. Does your modem also include a switch/router in one box? Also a lot of times ISPs tie your IP address to some physical address (MAC) like one of your router's interfaces or such

Answer (score 0):

I presume your modem is not acting as a DHCP server and so is not giving your pc an IP address. When you were connected to your wireless router this was handing out the IP address for the PC to use.
You can do two things.
1. See if your modem has the capability to act as a DHCP server
2. Statically assign an IP address to your PC

Comment: I don't know if my modem has DHCP capabilities. But if I try to set a static ip(by checking which one my router received, releasing the ip in my router, then setting it on my pc) I still get no connection.

Comment: why not set your pc to connect wirelessly, note down the IP address it receives and then replicate with the static setup. Does that work? Also are you setting your Subnet mask / default gateway / DNS Servers correctly when you statically assign the address? Take all this info from ipconfig /all